Recto tono in plural
Would I be correct in thinking that the plural of Recto tono is Rectis tonis?

Yes. You should know, though, that rēctō tonō and rēctīs tonīs are both in the ablative case, not the nominative case. The nominative case is normally what you use when importing a noun from another language. In the ablative case, the meaning is more like "in a straight tone" or "in straight tones".

@BenKovitz Thanks!
